# Pruning the list of running GUI applications that have been "idle" for > 24 hours?

Tags: gnome, desktop, productivity

I open lots of GUI applications -- mostly, instances of Nautilus or Terminal -- without closing them promptly.  Consequently, my list of active applications gets big.  Besides the drain on the RAM, switching between GUI applications that share a same icon becomes a chore.

Is there a way to work more efficiently?  For instance, by automatically closing the applications that haven't been used for a while, let's say 24 hours.  Or by using a tool that lets users to close applications quickly, instead of having to switch to each application and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

#### System

- Debian GNU/Linux 6
- Gnome 2.30

Comment: Ram is probably not an issue, as memory will be mostly shared between instances.

Comment: The best way to undo something, is not to do it. Have you considered not opening so many applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`killall` may be you friend here.

You can kill all processes by name, there are also options for older-than.

e.g. `killall -I --older-than=1d nautilus` to kill all nautilus older than 1 day.